# Header, dots in split equation and parentheses around footnote numbers

Tags: formatting, equations, header-footer, footnotes

I am currently struggling with a couple of things (in the `\documentclass{book}`):

1. I want the header to be something like this:

   - on the even pages: roman chapter number . chapter name
   - on the odd pages: `§` section number . section name
2. I wanted the footnote number to be in  parentheses so I wrote `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}` but this made parentheses only in superscript. I need to have the number in the superscript and regular parentheses around it.
3. I need to add a line of dots after a couple of equations. So far I've managed to do something like this:

   ```
   \begin{split}  
   p' (x) &  = a_1 +2a_2x + 3a_3x^2 + \ldots + na_nx^{n-1},  
   p''(x) &  = 1\cdot 2a_2 + 2\cdot 3a_3x + \ldots + (n-1)na_nx^{n-2},  
   \makebox[1cm]{\dotfill} & \makebox[6.9cm]{\dotfill}  
   p^{(n)}(x) & = 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot na_n.  
   \end{split}
   ```

but this makes a small space where `&` is. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the default page style (headings).  Personally I would have used `myheadings` or created a new page style.

Note that the new footnote mark is used both in the text and in the footnote listing.  If you only want it to appear in the text, just use `(\footnote{...})` instead.

The `split` environment is intended for single equations.  For multiple equations you should use `align` (or `align*` if you don't want equation numbers).  The tricky bit was aligning the dots to the previous line.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\rlap{\thepage}\hfil{\slshape\leftmark}\hfil}%
      \def\@oddhead{\hfil{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\llap{\thepage}}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \Roman{chapter}. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \S \arabic{section}. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}

\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{($^\@thefnmark$)}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}% resets definitions

\newsavebox{\leftbox}
\newsavebox{\rightbox}

\begin{document}
\chapter{C Title}

\section{s title}

\savebox{\leftbox}{$\displaystyle p''(x)$}% must be predefined
\savebox{\rightbox}{$\displaystyle \strut = 1\cdot 2a_2 + 2\cdot 3a_3x + \ldots + (n-1)na_nx^{n-2}$}%

\begin{align}  
p' (x) &= a_1 +2a_2x + 3a_3x^2 + \ldots + na_nx^{n-1},\\
\usebox{\leftbox} &\usebox{\rightbox},\\
 &\hspace{-\wd\leftbox}\makebox[\dimexpr \wd\leftbox+\wd\rightbox]{$\dotfill$}\notag\\
p^{(n)}(x) &= 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot na_n.  
\end{align}

Footnote test \footnote{This is a test}.

\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I have one issue though. The dots should be aligned horizontally not vertically. I'm sorry for not specifying that in the question. Is there any easy way to modify your code so the dots will be spanned on the whole line (from the `p` to the comma that ends the previous line)? Also, the names in the heading are capitalized and I want them to be in `\normalfont`(I believe that's the proper command) and centered. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I first tried using \tikzmark, but couldn't get it to work.  So I used saveboxes instead.  (I still think vertical dots are better.)  Where do you want the page numbers?

Comment: Left upper corner for the even pages and right upper corner for the odd pages.